# How to get Selenium close action?

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I have recently started using Selenium, and while it works very well I am stuck with what I thought would be a very simple step. I would like to be able to run a method if a user closes the `Webdriver` (Right now it just crashes and leaves all my temp files intact.) I know  If I was using a `JFrame` I could just add a `WindowListener`, does anyone know if a similar thing exists for Selenium WebDrivers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using `JUnit` to execute my tests and it has [TestWatcher](http://junit.czweb.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) class that you could extend. So you can possibly `@Override` the `starting`, `finished`, `failed` and `succeeded` methods to take appropriate action.